# [PHP]Using a "Path Argument"

Tags: php, url, arguments

all. I've seen this on many websites...
Bacilly they have a way of getting input from a URL (Not `$_GET`")
Like `mydomain.com/user/John`. And if that users exists,it'll run a script. Else,it will return a "User not found" deal,rather than a 404.So i'm wondering how they run scripts non existent directories. Thanks!

Comment: Look up url rewriting, mod_rewrite, pretty urls ...

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Found a solution